# deadlock between update on a set of rows and select some of the same rows

Tags: sql-server-2008, deadlock, database-deadlocks

I have two SPID's running as transcations and below is what each one does among other things.

SPID A -

1. Updates rows 1-10 from table 1
2. .......

SPID B -

1. Updates row 5 from table 1
2. Selects rows 4,5 & 6 from table 1 and updates a row in table 2.
3. ......
4. ......

I'm facing a deadlock scenario where SPID A has updated row 4 and waiting for X lock on the clustered index to update row 5 and SPID B is in step 2 waiting for a S lock on the clustered index for row 4 which is in X lock by SPID A.
There is also a non clustered index on table 1 but it does not cover the select query, so it looks up the clustered index. I'm assuming that even if I make it a covering index SPID A will hold a lock on the non clustered index making SPID B to wait on it. 
I'm considering escalating the isolation level to serialization so that SPID A which is more or less updating the whole table will have to wait to acquire its lock if SPID B has already  started on its update to row 5. Also it will prevent SPID B from acquiring the x locks if SPID A has already begun. SPID A currently executes every 20 minutes and holds on to the transaction for about 10 secs.

What other suggestions would any of you have for me to get rid of this deadlock?
Thanks.

Comment: If youn can move the step 2 in B,  "2.Selects rows 4,5 & 6" above step 1 with a UPDLOCK hint, that will solve your issue.

Comment: I can't move step 2 as I need the updated values from row 5 along with the other current versions of the other rows 4,6 etc..

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at [this blog entry](http://goo.gl/3YaVz). This contains a handy **SQL script to display the locks**, that are present now, and it displays all information about them:

```
SELECT
db.name DBName,
tl.request_session_id,
wt.blocking_session_id,
OBJECT_NAME(p.OBJECT_ID) BlockedObjectName,
tl.resource_type,
h1.TEXT AS RequestingText,
h2.TEXT AS BlockingTest,
tl.request_mode
FROM sys.dm_tran_locks AS tl
INNER JOIN sys.databases db ON db.database_id = tl.resource_database_id
INNER JOIN sys.dm_os_waiting_tasks AS wt ON tl.lock_owner_address = wt.resource_address
INNER JOIN sys.partitions AS p ON p.hobt_id = tl.resource_associated_entity_id
INNER JOIN sys.dm_exec_connections ec1 ON ec1.session_id = tl.request_session_id
INNER JOIN sys.dm_exec_connections ec2 ON ec2.session_id = wt.blocking_session_id
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(ec1.most_recent_sql_handle) AS h1
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(ec2.most_recent_sql_handle) AS h2
GO
```

In general, my guess is simply that **your SQL Server uses PAGE lock** by default (like every SQL Server), and this way an update on a single row can block all rows on the same PAGE. See [this article](http://goo.gl/9oEVW) to get more understanding of locking in SQL server, and [this blog just for fun](http://tedwise.com/2010/03/15/select-deadlocks-in-sql-server-aka-sql-server-sucks/?trk_event=search_click&trk_result_index=0). The blog explains, that it can be strange after an oracle, that **a select can block an update**, which is possible in SQL server.

To avoid your problem, **use the [ROWLOCK](http://goo.gl/Ilu7K) hint in the updates**, and you will loose a bit performance and your deadlocks as well. Second solution is to set lower deadlock detection timeout in SQL server, and catch the SQL server error, and if it is a deadlock victim error, try again.